# StylePlayerView controller xml overriding play and pause button not working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, exoplayer

I updated my project exoplayer dependency, and i was updating my code with StylePlayerView (customized layout from exoplayer) reference, but when i  executed my code the overrating about this 2 buttons PLAY and PAUSE, are not working, y  use PLAY_PAUSE and works, but i want to customize this icons.. so if someone can help me, i really apreace it.
psdt.- And sorry about mi english because i speak spanish.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/customized_controller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/transparentBackground">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/exo_rew"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/replay"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Rewind"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_replay_10" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/exo_play_pause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/play"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_play"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/exo_play"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/play"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible"
                style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_play"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/exo_pause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/pause"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible"
                style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_pause" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/exo_ffwd"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/fast_forward"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="@style/ExoMediaButton.FastForward"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_forward_30" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exo_duration"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/whitePrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.DefaultTimeBar
            android:id="@+id/exo_progress"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:buffered_color="@color/grey_accent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/exo_duration"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/exo_position"
            app:played_color="@color/blueLight"
            app:unplayed_color="@color/whiteSecondary"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bt_fullscreen"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/full_screen"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen_24"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exo_progress"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/exo_position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/whitePrimary"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bt_close_player"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/close"
            android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_left"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txvChapterTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textColor="@color/whitePrimary"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_close_player"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/lnSettings"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bt_close_player"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bt_close_player" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lnSettings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="12dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bt_close_player"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bt_close_player">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bt_settings"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/title_settings"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_24" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this issue for me by overriding the style and drawables. I created a new style on my values file like below:

```
<style name="ExoStyledControls.Button.Center.PlayPause">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/exo_styled_controls_pause</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/exo_controls_play_description</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/exo_icon_padding</item>
</style>
<drawable name="exo_styled_controls_pause">@drawable/exo_styled_control_pause</drawable>
<drawable name="exo_styled_controls_play">@drawable/exo_styled_control_play</drawable>
```

The drawables exo_styled_control_play and exo_styled_control_pause should contain your own drawable code.

Do not forget to invalidate cache and restart if it doesn't work right away.

Comment: Where did you put that <drawable /> tag? Is it right below style? And you did not reference `@drawable/exo_styled_control_play`? Can you please explain?

Comment: The <drawable /> tags are in their own file, not right below style here.
**@drawable/exo_styled_control_play** & **@drawable/exo_styled_control_pause** are your own drawable files to replace play and pause buttons with.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It worked. Thank you so much.